# Capture navigation text on click of item

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to capture using jQuery or Javascript the text value from parent classes in a site navigation
Example navigation:

Level 1 - bish
Level 2 - bash

if I click on Level 2 - 'bash' I'd like to capture level 1 text 'bish' into variable

An example of code I'm working with

```
`<li class="class1">
  <a href="/bish" class="class2">
    <div class="class3">
       <p class="class4 level1">bish</p>
    </div>
  </a>
       <ul class="class5">
    <div class="class4">
         <li class="class6">
           <div class="class7">
             <a href="/bash" class="class8 level2">bash</a>
    </div>
         </li>
      </ul>
           </div>
</li>`
```

Id be grateful for any help.

I'm expecting that the value bish will output to a variable. The challenges I'm having is that because it's navigation the same class values are being used for other navigation.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
$('.level2').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  let level1 = $(this).closest('.class1').find('.level1').text();
  console.log(level1);
});
```